# ng build/serve only use the `environmentSource` file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Whenever I try to prepare build/serve for production env, angular cli only use `environmentSource` for the env's variables.

#### Versions.

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.5
node: 8.2.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.0.2
@angular/common: 4.0.2
@angular/compiler: 4.0.2
@angular/core: 4.0.2
@angular/forms: 4.0.2
@angular/http: 4.0.2
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.2
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.2
@angular/router: 4.0.2
@angular/cli: 1.2.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.2
```

#### .angular-cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "ng2angle"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "app/core/preloader/preloader.scss",
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "app/core/preloader/preloader.js",
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

#### Build Command

```
ng build --environment=prod --no-aot
ng build --environment=prod
ng build -e=prod
ng build --prod
```

Comment: What command are you running to build ?

Comment: @IvanMladenov i just updated my question. please have a look.

Comment: Extract a `environment.dev.ts` file to use for development and leave the `environment.ts` file empty

Comment: @IvanMladenov yeah that resolve my issue, could you post this as answer, so I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Extract a `environment.dev.ts` file with your development configurations and leave the `environment.ts` file empty

Comment: now facing a issue about variables, application getting the undefined variable from respective env's
` Cannot read property 'auth_lock_key' of undefined`

Comment: `ng serve -e=prod/dev/staging` giving following error `src/environments/environment.ts' is not a module.`